# Duplicate git repo with all branches, tags and what-not

Tags: git

I need to duplicate a repo that I have in Bitbucket (if that matters) preserving history, branches, tags, etc. I saw recommendations with `git push --mirror`. However, I need to make sure that I do end up with 2 independent repos and that if I make changes (push new code, or delete branch, etc) in on off them, it wouldn't be reflected in the other. From what I've read, it is not clear to me that this is what happens with `--mirror`. What are the correct commands to achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean `git clone --mirror`? It should do what you describe.

Comment: actually, I saw both `git clone --mirror` and `git push --mirror`. So now I am confused even more. Does `git clone --mirror` create a new independent repo? Because I think I've read (and maybe I misunderstood) that `--mirror` creates a reference to original repo. And if so, in my understanding, changing clone would also affect original. Also if `git clone --mirror` is the right command, where do I specify the new repo name? Could you please provide a complete set of commands

Comment: `git clone --mirror` creates a new local repository, just like the regular `git clone` command. It will by default use the remote repository name as the name of the local directory, but you can of course provide an alternative.

Comment: All repositories' refnames are completely independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really pretty simple, once you understand what a repository is and how cloning works.  It's important to distinguish between the *repository* and the *hosting server* if any, too.

#### Hosting servers

Bitbucket are a hosting server.  This means they provide a way for clients (you and other people) to identify yourself (and themselves) to the hosting server: to prove to the hosting server that you are who you say you are.  It is then up to *them* to decide, based on your having proven that you are who you claim to be, what you can *do* on that server—e.g., what repositories you can access, in what way.  (As with most hosting providers, you can pay them different amounts of money to get various services from them.)

#### Git repositories

A *Git repository*, by contrast, is—mostly—a *collection of commits*, plus some auxiliary data:

- Branch and tag names contain commit hash IDs.  You need these because commit hash IDs look random (though they're not actually random at all).
- A *bare* repository mostly has just these two databases: the commits (and other internal Git objects needed to make them all useful) and the names.
- A regular (non-bare) repository has these same two databases—the commits and other objects, plus the names—*and* provides a *work-tree* in which you can do new work.

Compare bare and non-bare repositories.  In a bare repository, no one can actually do any work: a bare repository can hold commits, and change the hash IDs stored in its names, but to get *new* commits, you will, in general, have to get them from some other repository.  This makes bare repositories good receptacles for `git push` operations, because `git push` means *send some commit(s) to some other repository, then ask them—the other repository—to update their names to remember the latest commit(s)*.

Each commit in any repository has a unique hash ID.  Hash IDs are big and ugly; no human can ever remember them reliably.  But *every* Git agrees that *this* commit, whatever it is, has *this particular hash ID*.  That's how two Gits coordinate with each other.  When you have your repository, you run `git fetch` to have your Git call up some other Git and get various commits (and other internal objects) from it.  Their Git says: *I have the name `master` associated with commit hash `a123456...`*, for instance.  Your Git can now check: Do you have commit `a123456...`?  If not, and you want it, you ask them for it.

While humans cannot remember hash IDs reliably, they are pretty good at using *names*.  So a *branch name* like `master` holds exactly one hash ID.  What good is just one hash ID?  Well, it remembers a particular commit; and *every* commit can—and most do—have *another* commit's hash ID inside them.

These hash IDs link commits together.  But they do this *backwards*.  When you make a *new* commit, your new commit records the hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit.  We say that the new commit *points to* its *parent*.  That parent commit, of course, also points to *its* parent—the grandparent of your new commit.  The grandparent points to *its* parent, which points back to yet another parent, and so on.

What this means is that as long as a branch name holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, Git can work backwards from there, all the way to the very first commit ever.  This first commit is unusual: it has no parent.  That's how Git knows it's the first commit and can stop.

Thus, the way a branch name works is that it simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  That chain ends at that commit.  This doesn't mean there are no newer commits: it only means that *that* branch ends at that commit.  Hence we can have a situation like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
               \
                I <-J   <-- develop
```

Here the name `develop` identifies commit `J`, which points back to `I`, which points back to `H`, and so on.  (The uppercase letters here stand in for the real hash IDs, which we can't remember anyway.)  Meanwhile the name `master` identifies commit `H`, which points back to `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.  This means commits up through `H` are on *both* branches, and commits `I` and `J` are on `develop`.

Note that history, in a Git repository, is just the commits.  The commits *are* the history.  If you have the commits, you have the history.  If not, you don't.  The branch names tell you where to *start*, and after that, you—or Git—just follow the backwards-pointing links from commits to their parents.

#### Cloning

You now know what a repository is: it's a collection of commits (and other Git objects) plus names, such as branch names.  That by itself is pretty useful, but to make it even more useful, Git supports the concept of *cloning* a repository.

To clone a repository, we use the `git clone` command—but this is really just shorthand for *run six other commands in sequence* (with some cleanup if they fail).  The six commands are:

1. `mkdir` (or your local computer equivalent) to make a new empty directory.  (Git can use an existing empty directory instead, if you like.)  This is where the new repository will live.  The rest of the clone operation proceeds in this empty directory.
2. `git init`, or `git init --bare` if you choose to make a bare clone.  This creates either the files that Git uses to hold everything, in this directory, for a bare clone, or makes the directory `.git` and puts all the Git files into `.git`, leaving the otherwise-empty-except-for-`.git` directory as your work-tree.
3. `git remote add url`.  This creates the name `origin` (or some other name of your choice), which holds the given *url* for later re-use.  The URL you provide must be one which, when Git tries to connect to it, answers that Internet "phone number" with the various programs that let the two Gits talk to each other.  One Git—yours—will be *your* Git on your system.  The other Git is probably on a hosting provider.<sup>1</sup>
4. `git config various-options`.  This step is only used if you've provided configuration options during your clone.
5. `git fetch remote-name`.  Usually the remote name is `origin`, but if you changed it in step 3, this uses the name you set up in step 3.  This connects your Git—which currently has *no* commits, *no* branches, *no* tags, and no other names like this—to their Git, which presumably does have some commits and branch names and tag names and so on.

   The fetch step obtains, from them, their branch and tag and other names.  It then behaves in a way we'll discuss in just a moment.  Mostly, though, it winds up downloading every commit and other Git object from *their* Git, so that your Git has all the objects.  Then it fiddles with the names, too.
6. Having copied some or all Git objects, and—typically—turned all of their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names, your Git goes on to do the last step, which is to run `git checkout`.  Your Git *doesn't* do this if you selected a bare clone, as the point of `git checkout` is to extract some commit into your work-tree, and a bare clone has no work-tree.

These are the six steps of cloning.  You run:

```
git clone <url>
```

and your Git: makes a directory and enters it, runs `git init`, runs `git remote add`, runs `git config` if needed, runs `git fetch`, and runs `git checkout`.  It's now time to talk about the way Git changes names, because that's what you need for doing your particular task here.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you want to provide the hosting service yourself, *you* must set up all the stuff required to let a Git talk to you.  This is complicated since you need to be secure and do authentication and run the right Git plumbing commands when someone invokes your service.  That's why most people use hosting providers, especially when the price is somewhere from free<sup>2</sup> to just a few dollars a month.

<sup>2</sup>"Free", of course, means that *you* are the product.  They're getting something from the fact that you are using them as a hosting provider.  For instance, GitHub was pretty early on in this give-free-hosting-for-individuals system, so that everyone uses it a lot, so that companies that go to host heavy duty repositories have employees that are comfortable with using GitHub, so that the companies pay GitHub for hosting services.  That's still a pretty good deal for individuals.

---

#### How Git modifies names during `git fetch`

When you create a *non-bare* (regular) clone, the `git remote` add step—step 3—sets up a configuration variable.  The standard setting for this configuration variable (whose standard name is `remote.origin.fetch`) is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This configuration variable tells your Git *what branch names are interesting*—in this case, *all* branch names—and *how to rename them*.

Their Git, when it lists their branch names, might tell your Git: *I have `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/develop`* for instance.  That would be the case if they had just two branch names, `master` and `develop`.  The full names of these branches include the `refs/heads/` part in front, so those are the names your Git will see.

When their Git lists their *tag* names, they will come over looking like, e.g., `refs/tags/v0.9` and `refs/tags/v1.0`.  The `refs/tags/` string is at the front and the rest is the name of the tag.  Your Git *doesn't* modify these names.  It just either takes them, or doesn't, in a rather complicated way for a regular, non-bare repository.  (We'll get to bare repositories in a moment.)

With the *branch names*, though, your Git normally—in a non-bare repository, again—*renames* their branch names.  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`. More precisely, their `refs/heads/master` becomes your `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  This happens through that configuration entry.  Here it is again:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The plus sign at the front is the *force* flag, which we can mostly ignore here.  The rest of this says: *when their name starts with `refs/heads/`, match it, then rename it by changing that to `refs/remotes/origin/`*.  So their `refs/heads/master` matches, and your Git changes it to `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Their `refs/heads/develop` matches, and your Git changes it to `refs/remotes/origin/develop`.

Hence, when you run `git fetch`, your Git will find *all* of their branch names "interesting" and will copy *all* of them.  You will get *all* of their branch-named commits–remember, each name holds one hash ID—and all of those commits' parents, and all of the parents' parents, and so on.  Then your Git will *rename* all of those names, and you will end up with `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and so on, with each of these names identifying the *same* commit hash as their *branch* name.

#### Using `--mirror` changes the fetch setting

When you use `git clone --mirror`, your Git:

- makes the repository `--bare` (so that it has no work-tree and step 6 of clone is skipped), *and*
- changes the `fetch` line to read `+refs/*:refs/*`.

It's this second change that is the key here.  This makes *all* refs interesting, no matter how they are spelled.  Branch names are spelled `refs/heads/*`.  Tag names are spelled `refs/tags/*`.  Remote-tracking names, if they have any, are spelled `refs/remotes/*`.  (The `*` matches all of `origin/master` in this case.)  Notes, if they have any, are under `refs/notes/*`, and so on: *all* Git references, except for oddball special cases like `HEAD`, start with `refs/`.  So `refs/*` matches all refs.  (Again, the `*` matches across slashes, unlike shell globs.)

So, if you run:

```
git clone --mirror url
```

your Git will execute steps 1 through 5, and in step 5, will copy *all* of their names to exactly-matching names in your repository.  You will get all the internal objects—all the commits and other Git objects needed—to make these names useful.  You now have a *mirror clone*.

#### Copying a whole repository with `git push --mirror`

Now, suppose you've made a mirror clone on your own machine, that has a complete copy—including all names—of some hosting provider's repository.  Suppose further that, on the same or some other provider, you have used their web interface, or whatever it is that they provide, to create a *new* but empty repository.  You can now run `git push <url>` to send some or all of your commits (and other Git objects), and some or all of your *names*, to their new, totally-empty Git.

In this case, you will want to send them all of your *names*, so `git push --mirror` does the trick.  This uses the same `refs/*:refs/*` pair of names to say that your Git should take *all* of your names—`refs/*`—and use that to send them the *last* object for that branch, or whatever, from which they'll ask for all previous objects too.  Then, your Git will ask them to set, in their repository, the *same* name that you have in yours, to hold that same raw hash ID, whatever it is.

Once this process finishes, your own copy of this repository—your bare, mirror clone—is no longer useful!  You can simply remove it.  You were only using it to get everything *from* repository #1, so as to `git push` it all to repository #2.

If you're doing this across separate hosting providers—e.g., copying from GitHub to Bitbucket, or GitLab to GitHub, or whatever—you will almost certainly have to use this intermediate mirror clone on your side, because they have no reason to provide a service that does this directly.  But if you're copying from Bitbucket repository #1 to Bitbucket repository #2, for instance, they may well provide a shortcut.  Whether they do, and how, is up to them, and you would have to ask them.

#### Forking

A common shortcut is often called *forking*, but forking leaves a tracing connection between the copy and the original.  Exactly *how* this tracing works depends on the hosting provider: it enables them offer things that standalone Git does not, such as *pull requests*.  Because standalone Git doesn't have these, and the hosting providers do, that makes you more likely (they hope, anyway) to use *their* services.  So they'll tend to have features that other perhaps don't.  They will tend to provide them in incompatible ways, to some extent: standards are great, but so is lock-in, depending on one's point of view.

This tracing connection may well be totally harmless.  Perhaps you should just fork the repository.  But if you don't want to, and the hosting provider doesn't give you a "fork without connection" option, you can always do a mirror-clone followed by a mirror-push followed by deleting the temporary intermediate repository.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>3</sup>Alternatively, if you want, you can *keep* the intermediate repository, converting it from a bare mirror clone to a regular clone, and changing the associated `origin` URL if you like.  But the *way* you can do that is not part of this answer.